# count between time range

Tags: excel, time, range, counting

Hi there  i have this table with 5 columns Date,Time,ID, Name, Car number

what i need is to count how many people attend in each day and between range of time for example ( 5 people attend in 12/12/2010 at between 6am and 8am and another 5 person comes at 1pm i need to count in each time zone from 6 to 8 and from 12pm  to 2pm )

im using this to count the time but its going to take long time because i'm separating time manually  =COUNTIFS(B2:B26;">0") for each cell and i tried this but it doesn't work 
=COUNTIFS(B:B;">=TIME(5;0;0)";B:B;">=TIME(11;0;0)")

[image: my data]

Comment: I've adjusted your tech tags so that you are actually receiving attention from the [tag:excel] forum. That looks to be a **Structured Table**. Why are you not using proper referencing for a [Structured Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **pivot table** for that.

1. Add a new column at the end of the table and name it *period*.
2. Use **IF** function to convert time values to Morning, Afternoon, and Evening. The new values should be on the new column called *period*
3. Select the complete table and create a pivot table (should be in the data menu)
4. The structure of the pivot table is easy: **Row Data** should have both *date* and *period* columns and **Values** should have *Count of Name*
5. Apply the pivot table. Done.